# map internal port 80 to localhost port 80 in docker

Tags: docker

I had ran the docker image and it is showing the following:

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                           NAMES
cbcc0a6d5c1e        programming_applicationserver       "bin/wait-for-it.sh …"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 5436/tcp                    programming_applicationserver_run_3
4cb5bdbb6c1d        programming_onlineaccountverifier   "bin/wait-for-it.sh …"   5 days ago          Up About an hour    127.0.0.1:5435->5435/tcp                        programming_onlineaccountverifier_1
bf39ba383cec        programming_onlineballotregulator   "bin/docker_entrypoi…"   5 days ago          Up About an hour    8545/tcp, 127.0.0.1:5434->5434/tcp, 30303/tcp   programming_onlineballotregulator_1
```

but when I go to localhost:80 nothing is shown.
What should I do now ?

Comment: Could you answer these questions? What os are you using? Which software are you using to run these containers (e.g. docker machine)? What means "nothing is shown" exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to an error in the application itself and not docker.

To verify that, you can go into the container and make sure the application is port is working reachable:

```
docker exec -it programming_applicationserver_run_3 bash
```

Once you are inside the container, try accessing the port using one of the following command:

```
curl localhost:80
wget localhost:80
```

If non of these are successful, this would imply that the problem is related to the application and not to docker itself.